# Get the distance and bearing of each pathline using Leaflet.PolylineMeasure plugin?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins, bearing

I have been playing with `polylinemeasure:change` and I see I can get the value of the total distance easily with `currentLine.distance`.

But how can I get the value of each pathline distance and its bearing?

This is the furthest I went:

```
// Define some maps options
var mapOptions = {
  center: [20.27, -157],
  zoom: 7
};

//Create a map and assign it to the map div
var map = L.map("leafletMapid", mapOptions);

//  Add a baselayer
var baselayer = L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

baselayer.addTo(map);

// Create polylineMeasure

const pMeasure = L.control.polylineMeasure();
pMeasure.addTo(map);

map.on("polylinemeasure:change", (currentLine) => {
  console.log(currentLine.distance);
});
```

You can see this example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/polylinemeasure-from-points-forked-xux7si?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking source code of `L.control.polylineMeasure` plugin shows that bearings data is calculated only when option `showBearings` is set to `true` and even then data is stored only in marker tooltip.

Solution is to 'steal' bearings calculation function from plugin source code end calculate bearings from `polylineMeasure._currentLine.circleCoords` coordinates.

Code could then look something like this (`showBearings` is set to `true` to check correctness of the method):

```
let polylineMeasure = L.control.polylineMeasure ({
  position:'topleft',
  unit:'kilometres',
  clearMeasurementsOnStop: false,
  showClearControl: true,
  showUnitControl: true,
  showBearings: true
});
polylineMeasure.addTo (map);

var calcAngle = function (p1, p2, direction) {
    var lat1 = p1.lat / 180 * Math.PI;
    var lat2 = p2.lat / 180 * Math.PI;
    var lng1 = p1.lng / 180 * Math.PI;
    var lng2 = p2.lng / 180 * Math.PI;
    var y = Math.sin(lng2-lng1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(lng2-lng1);
    if (direction === "inbound") {
        var brng = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI + 180).toFixed(0);
    } else {
        var brng = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI + 360).toFixed(0);
    }
    return (brng % 360);
}

function debugevent(e) {
  var coords = polylineMeasure._currentLine.circleCoords;
  var lastInd = coords.length - 1;
  if (lastInd > 0) {
    var outb = calcAngle(coords[lastInd - 1], coords[lastInd], 'outbound');
    var inb = calcAngle(coords[lastInd], coords[lastInd - 1], 'inbound');
    console.log('Line ' + lastInd + ' bearings:');
    console.log('  - start out: ' + outb);
    console.log('  - end in: ' + inb);
  }
}

map.on('polylinemeasure:change', debugevent);
```

This measuring:

[image]

would give this result:

```
Line 1 bearings:
  - start out: 356
  - end in: 356
Line 2 bearings:
  - start out: 290
  - end in: 280
Line 3 bearings:
  - start out: 218
  - end in: 213
Line 4 bearings:
  - start out: 153
  - end in: 157
```

Comment: This is great! Would it be crazy if the distance for each pathline was calculated like this `var dist = polylineMeasure._currentLine.distance[lastInd] - polylineMeasure._currentLine.distance[lastInd - 1]` ?

Comment: Seems perfectly OK.